# Email sending from address is gmail with django

Tags: django, email, gmail

Minor but annoying issue, I have setup my django app to use my company's gmail account to send emails. The sending works fine, but the from in the emails is always the gmail account. Here are me settings/code - I have changed all the addresses etc, but to be sure everything works fine except for the from e-mail.

```
def send_discrepency_email(action, cart, atype):
    r = False
    user = cart.user
    subject = "%s - User Discrepency Response for order %s (%s)" % (action.upper(), cart.web_order_id, cart.syspro_order_id)
    message = "The user %s (%s) has opted to %s his/her order with the following discrepency type: %s." %(user.email, user.customer_id, action.upper(), atype)
    try:
        e = EmailMessage(subject, message, 'no-reply@rokky.com', ["ecommerce_requests@rokky.com", "pewet@s6688m.com"])
        e.send(fail_silently=False)
        r = True
    except Exception as e:
        print "Error sending discrepency email: %s" % e

    return r
```

Note: for the code I have also tried overriding with the headers kwarg to no avail.

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "ecommerce_requests@rokkyy.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'no-actual-account@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'fakepword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

Is this even doable with gmail, I swear I used this once before and it worked fine.

**In short, no matter what changes I make, the FROM email is always no-actual-account@gmail.com**

Comment: You  mean to say the from is `ecommerce_requests@rokkyy.com` instead of `no-reply` ?

Comment: no, sorry the FROM email is always no-actual-account@gmail.com instead of no-reply. I just added that SERVER_EMAIL setting before posting this to see if it helped, I will remove from my example.

Comment: Did you ever solve this or is it impossible with GMAIL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a security setting with gmail.  I ran into this issue with a rails app that I wrote.  The from address must either be the account you sign in with aka 'no-actual-account@gmail.com' or an alias to that account.  You can always just set the reply-to and get a similar effect to changing the from address.  Or you will have to use a different SMTP server.

Comment: I should probably close this - i am at a different job now anyway :) you are essentially correct, we just switched to send grid. Problem solved.